# Avoid involuntary data pushing to iCloud during updates

Tags: icloud, privacy

I run iCloud on iOS/macOS with only "Contacts" (and iMessage) enabled, because I don't want other data copied out of my device.

However, it seems that every time I upgrade iOS/macOS (and possibly when logging out/in of iCloud), that all other iCloud settings are forcibly enabled without my consent.

And you don't notice this until the device is up and running again, and then probably a lot of data has already been copied to iCloud before you manage to turn it off.

How can I make sure no data is copied to iCloud except what I have expressly chosen myself? Will it suffice to disable Wi-Fi before updates, since (I think) iCloud doesn't sync over Cellular Data.

Please provide step-by-step instructions for both iOS and macOS that are watertight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a **bug** that affected the update to **iOS 10.3**. Apple has resolved this issue with iOS 10.3.1.

See also [Apple Warns iCloud Users Some Disabled Services Were Accidentally Re-enabled in iOS 10.3](https://www.macrumors.com/2017/04/04/icloud-services-reenabled-ios-10-3/)

iCloud sync settings are not supposed to change after an iOS update. In the case of iOS 10.3 this was due to a bug.

To answer your question: You **don't need to change any settings** to prevent iOS to enable any iCloud sync settings with 10.3.1 and higher. Older iOS releases (10.2.1 and 10.3) can not be updated to any more.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Felt like a sly ploy to put unknowing users onto iCloud usage. I have a slight feeling this has happened before too, but I'm not sure. I'll post updates here if it happens again.

Comment: Yes, please keep us updated if it ever happens again.